# Remove all non-word characters but "."

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

What is the easiest way to remove all non-word characters of a filename?

The dot at the end before the extension is obviously needed, so all symbols like "`-`" or "`*`" or "`?`" should be removed except "`.`"

Something like this:

```
$filename = preg_replace("/[^\.]\W/", "", $filename);
```

Comment: what about underscores(_) ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use something like that:

```
$filename = preg_replace("/\W(?=.*\.[^.]*$)/", "", $filename);
```

The regex will match any non-word character ('word character' here is defined by the class `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) from a filename as long as there's a period for the extension.

This will also take into consideration possible file names such as `file.name.txt` and correctly return `filename.txt` (the first dot not being the dot for file extension).

Answer (score 3):

Why not:

```
$filename = preg_replace('/[^.\w]/', '', $filename);
```

This will simply remove any character that is *not* a word character or period.

Comment: I want to remove all non word characters except - (dash). Can I do the same?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts `preg_replace('/[^-\w]/', '', $filename)`. Note that `-` is a special character within character classes (`[…]`), so you usually have to escape it (e.g. `[…\-…]`) unless it appears as the first or last character of the class.

Answer (score 1):

My preference is

```
$filename = preg_replace('/[^.a-zA-Z]/', '', $filename);
```

If you want to add the digits too, then

```
$filename = preg_replace('/[^.a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $filename);
```